# git status is giving "Function not implemented" and "fatal: cannot use .git/info/exclude as an exclude file"

Tags: git

I am using gitbash and git version 2.20.1.windows.1. `commit`, `diff`, `branch` all work fine, but `git status` (the most basic command, surely?) fails. The error message is like this, where `fileA` and `fileB` are the tracked files in my repo:

```
$ git status
.gitignore: Function not implemented
fileA: Function not implemented
fileB: Function not implemented
fatal: cannot use .git/info/exclude as an exclude file
```

I can't spot anything strange about `.git/info/exclude` or `.gitignore`.

GitHub Desktop shows me the correct `status`, so that's my workaround for now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jan 2019: Check if this is releated to the recent [issue 1989](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1989)

> Disabling the fscache, reverting to 2.19.1 or moving the repo to the local drive fixes the problem.

```
git config --global core.fscache false
```

Update July 2020, as noted by [Rintze Zelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712389/rintze-zelle) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209815/git-status-is-giving-function-not-implemented-and-fatal-cannot-use-git-info/54211014#comment111304890_54211014):

> Updating to a newer version of [Git for Windows of >= v2.21.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1989#issuecomment-464802297) should now solve this problem as well.
> I no longer experienced this error after updating from git version 2.20.1.windows.1 to git version 2.27.0.windows.1

Comment: yes, I can confirm that moving the repo to the local drive or disabling fscache makes the error messages disappear.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. Take your well deserved up-vote!

Comment: Per https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1989#issuecomment-464802297, updating to a newer version of Git for Windows of >= v2.21.0 should now solve this problem as well. I no longer experienced this error after updating from `git version 2.20.1.windows.1` to `git version 2.27.0.windows.1`.

Comment: @RintzeZelle THank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I'm using git version 2.38.1.windows.1 and still experience this problem.
Seems to only happen when I try to run git clean -xf  on a directory that contains symlinks (from NPM installation), and when those symlinks can lead to circular references to the same directory

```
dirA -> dirB -> node_modules -> dirA
```

Setting

```
git config --global core.fscache false
```

did not help.