# Git - Unusual Path for CAfile

Tags: git, configuration

There's plenty of posts here about being behind a proxy and having to edit the `http.sslCAInfo` property in your config.

I just uninstalled/reinstalled Git for Windows x64 v2.19.1, made sure all %APPDATA% bits were gone as well.

Even if I set `http.sslCAInfo` to something like:

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt`, the infamous `error setting certificate verify locations` message appears but states the value for CAfile as:

`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

First of all, why the libexec folder? Additionally, from within a locally cloned repo, running `git config -l`, `git config --global -l`, and `git config --system -l` all return `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt`

Anyone seen this before or have a trick for determining where that seemingly incorrect value is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked with my own Git installation:

```
C:\Users\vonc>git config -l --show-origin|grep -i ssl
file:D:/prgs/git/PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit/mingw64/etc/gitconfig        

    http.sslcainfo=/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Check the value of that variable do start with "`/`": that means "Git installation path".

The [OP treblecode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734259/treblecode) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995787/git-unusual-path-for-cafile/57000402#comment100553145_57000402):

> Ended up fixing it just by cloning over SSH instead.
>
> So does cloning via HTTPS change how that information is determined by Git?

HTTPS means Git will need the value of `git config http.sslcainfo`

If Git is properly installed, this should work.
For testing, try in a CMD with a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56830002/6309).

Comment: Thanks VonC will give this a go. So depending on the scope, just need to change `http.sslcainfo` in that scope to the same path as the Git install path, yes?

Comment: @trebleCode I never needed to change that value: the important part if that it detects it installation path `D:/prgs/git/PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit`: the '/' will mean "concatenate the installation path" with that value. Check your %PATH%

Comment: @trebleCode Try the same commands in a CMD with a simplified PATH, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56830002/6309.

Comment: Ended up fixing it just by cloning over SSH instead. So does cloning via HTTPS change how that information is determined by Git?

Comment: @trebleCode OK. I have edited the answer accordingly and responded to your question from your comment.