# fatal: failed to read object 3e44f59efc1f44d4cb79eb454efc497e52332693: Function not implemented

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ with Git. I want to commit, but it ends with error:
`fatal: failed to read object 3e44f59efc1f44d4cb79eb454efc497e52332693: Function not implemented`
How can i fix that?

Edit: The problem occurs also then i execute git status.

Comment: Does it work from the command line outside the IntelliJ IDEA? Make sure that you have specified the latest git version in `(Settings/Preferences | Version Control | Git)` settings.

Comment: I tried it from the git gui and from the git command line

Comment: I think you need to make Git work from the command line first. Try to completely reinstall it on your machine. This discussion also seems to be similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739797/git-fatal-failed-to-read-object-xxx-invalid-argument

Comment: "Function not implemented" tends to imply some sort of OS-level mis-configuration, but see [git status is giving “Function not implemented” and “fatal: cannot use .git/info/exclude as an exclude file”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54209815/1256452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was: I'm using a network drive and offline files sync. One git file was not synchronized, so git can't find the missing file. A sync with the network-drive solved the problem.